# Ошибка при попытке закоммитить в SmartGit

Tags: git, linux

Я только что установил git & SmartGit. Создал новый локальный репозиторий и хотел сделать первый коммит, но вышла ошибка:

> Unable to create
> '/path/my_project/.git/index.lock':
> Permission denied

В итоге не могу закоммитить свои файлы. 
Может, кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой, прошу поделиться решением.
Может, нужны какие-то дополнительные настройки произвести?

Comment: ну так все же написано - нет прав у вас. Дайте себе права на директорию .git

Comment: права на /path/my_project/.git/ неверные.

Comment: удалите smartgit, он не нужен. Честно.

Answer (score 1):

Сделай `chmod -R 700 /path/my_project/`

Прав у тебя нет, как выше написали. Кстати, почему?

Comment: Спасибо, частично это помогло. 
Ваш ответ и комментарии других участников натолкнули меня на мысль, удалить папку с репозиторием и создать новый. Видимо, первый раз репозиторий как-то криво создался по непонятным мне причинам, а по второму разу прошло нормально.